# how can i bind angular property to uploaded file?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I am new to angular.

I am posting a model class to Web API controller. I have input file upload control, on change event I am attaching the property to the file. When I post the model, how can i bind the file on the server side?

here is my code:

```
 <input type="file" class="form-control" id="customFile"  (change)="onFileChange($event)"  [(ngModel)]="selectedObject.mJ_Icon"/>

onFileChange(evt:any): void {
    console.log(evt.target.files[0]);
    this.selectedObject.test = evt.target.files[0];
  }
```

Here is my c# class api core

```
public class Project
    {
        public int Project_Pk { get; set; }
        public string Project_Name { get; set; }
        public string Project_En { get; set; }
        public int Mj_ShowInHomePage { get; set; }
        public int Activrec { get; set; }
        public string MJ_Icon { get; set; }
        public byte[] Test { get; set; }
    }
```

When I post the code:

```
return this.http.post(UpdateProject_API ,JSON.stringify(project), httpOptions);
```

Test is null,

```
export class Project{
  project_Pk: number;
  project_Name: string;
  project_En: string;
  mj_ShowInHomePage: number;
  activrec: number;
  mJ_Icon: string;
  test:any;
```

Any reason ?

Comment: Only the "test" property is null ? What about the others?

Comment: are being binded

Comment: The file is logged with 'console.log(evt.target.files[0])'?

Comment: yes it is being logged

Comment: Can you also display your Typescript project class?

Answer (score 0):

You can not send binary data via Json. You must

1. use another content type like "multipart/form-data". Exemple: [Tutorial](https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-formdata/)
2. Or convert the image (if it's not to big) into base64

Comment: onFileChange(evt:any): void {
    const file = evt.target.files[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = () => {
        this.buffer = reader.result as string;
    };
    console.log(this.buffer);
  }

Comment: in the c# i get invalid base64 charecter